# How can I pass dataset from event listener

Tags: javascript, cordova

it doesn't pass any thing 
and if i send index on for loop it send all the last index of cell

I want distinguish between element has the same class
I  want alternative for  use 'unsafe-inline'  and send parameter via html

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function () {
    console.log("Device is ready!");
    //myApp.alert("aa","aa");

    var cell = document.querySelectorAll('.item-title');

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        cell[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            aaa(cell[i].dataset.index);
        }, true);

        //myApp.alert("aa"+, "aa");
        // x[i]=i;
    }
});

function aaa(id) {
    myApp.alert(id);
}
```

Comment: `cell[i].dataset` -> `this.dataset`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function () {
    console.log("Device is ready!");
    //myApp.alert("aa","aa");

    var cell = document.querySelectorAll('.item-title');

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        cell[i].addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
            const id = event.target.dataset.id;
            aaa(id);
        }, true);

        //myApp.alert("aa"+, "aa");
        // x[i]=i;
    }
});

function aaa(id) {
    myApp.alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Hey Alan, welcome to SO. Please could you explain what your code is doing, as it'll help other people understand what's going on - it's better for people understand something than to just copy+paste it blindly! Many thanks.